# Css and Autocomplete

Tags: css, autocomplete

I am using the autocomplete plugin in one of my applications the Autocomplete div that is being created by the autocomplete plugin has property `Position: Absolute;`. I have a drop down div in my navigation menu where i have an input field which triggers the auto complete function. Everything works fine except for when i hover over the autocomplete div. As soon as i hover on the autocomplete div the dropdown div dissappears cuz it is being shown by the following css :

```css
#nav li:hover > .subnav{
  display: block;
}

#nav .subnav {
  position:absolute;
  background:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  padding-right:15px;
  text-align:left;
  width:180px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  border-top:none;
  z-index:1200;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display:none;
  margin:6px -1px;
}
```

Here `#nav` is the ul that contains the navigation links and `.subnav` is the dropdown div.
i dont want .subnav div to dissappear once a user hovers over the autocomplete div to select an entry.

Comment: @BoltClock its the Ajax Autocomplete for Jquery - http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: @timaschew - What exact code do you want me to post ? as in HTML for the navigation menu ?